# If statement and datetime module python

Tags: python

I have two test files in a folder and this code

```py
def check(source):
    old_date = (datetime.datetime.now()) - (datetime.timedelta(days = 10))
    source_files=os.listdir(source)
    for file_name in source_files:
        if (datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(source+file_name)), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")) > old_date:
            print (str(datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(source+file_name)), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y") > old_date)+" copy")          
        else:
            print ("do not copy")

check("C:\Python\OldFilesCopier\Source\\")
```

Output is

```py
False copy
True copy
```

So to one file should apply IF statement for the second file should apply ELSE statement, but in both cases I went trough IF. Can't find the reason.

Comment: Because of `getctime` vs `getmtime`, probably...

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh. Broke my eyes. Thank you.